# Mysql connect by command line permission denied but workbench works fine

Tags: mysql

I got mysql host, username, password, port, then I use mysql workbench to connect, it's just fine.

But when I use command line:

> mysql -h x.x.x.x -u myusername  -P myport -pMYPASSWORD MY_DB_NAME

It reported error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myusername'@'mylocal_ip:55489' (using password: Yes)

First of all, the command line connection seems like auto add my local ip address and a random port to my username, can I make a connection without these tails?

Then why mysql workbench can connect success? Does workbench use different command from my command line command?

Comment: What about mysql -u username -p

Comment: @SudhirOjha same.